# TestNG: http://127.0.0.1:9085/ system cannot found specified path

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, testng

I am getting the following error:

```
 url = http://127.0.0.1:9085/nmc/rpc/get_nmc_mode
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \WebAPI_Files\nmcMode.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

I am running some test-cases on TestNG.
Could someone please help me figure out why I am getting this error.

THe XML file from where the inputs are being read is as follows:

```
<test name="WebAPI_Renderer" preserve-order="true" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="serverName" value="Server2" />  <!-- Remote server name-->
        <parameter name="rendererName" value="TM Player " /> <!-- Remote renderer name-->
        <parameter name="ContentServerIP" value="http://127.0.0.1:9000" /> <!-- Remote server IP -->
        <parameter name="OriginalContentFolder" value="C:/CONTENT" /> <!-- Location where the normal content is placed at remote server -->
        <parameter name="serverURL" value="http://127.0.0.1:9085" /> <!-- IP of any machine in network -->
        <parameter name="LogsLocation" value="C:/Java_Work/Java" />
        <parameter name="HelpFileLocation" value="C:/Java_Work/Java" />
        <parameter name="SearchContentFolder" value="C:/SearchContent" />
        <parameter name="URL1" value="http://127.0.0.1:9085" />
        <parameter name="URL2" value="http://127.0.0.1:9085" />
        <parameter name="contentURL" value="http://127.0.0.1:9000" />
```

Could some-one please help?
thanks 
Sunny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with TestNG: your code needs a certain file to exist and this file doesn't.